# Linux software for local version control

Tags: linux, version-control, offline

I am developing a software using Qt in Ubuntu 14.04. It is big project and I do it on leisure time. I have a single laptop and though I connect to internet, I don't like to store my code files in the cloud.

Is there a Linux (preferably installable in Ubuntu) software that performs version controlling without needing to connect to a server (i.e. the VCS repository is on the device itself)?

If possible add whether a GUI component exists for that software.

Comment: ⓐ Do you confuse ‘SVN’ (that is proper name of specific software) with ‘VCS’ (version control system in general)?

Comment: ⓑ If you do, then **any** version control system: SVN, GNU Bazaar, Git, Mercurial, etc. If you do not, then SVN, its repository can be local as well.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know VCS is the idea and SVN is a specific software that employs it. I will give SVN/GNU Bazaar a try. Does GIT has local repository?

Comment: Yes, all of VCS, I know, can store repository in local FS; Git and Hg actually can *not* work without doing it, afaik, they are pure DVCS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think for your project **[Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software))** is fitted best. Especially on Linux, it is...

- easy to install: `apt-get install git` / `yum install git`
- easy to get started with (just change into your projects top directory and run `git init` creates your local repository (a single sub-directory named `.git` inside the main directory)) and easy to maintain
- powerful, but nobody forces you to use all the power
- a simple GUI comes along (`gitk`), for a beginner I recommend to install an additional tool like [gitcola](http://git-cola.github.io/)
- to get started, there's a nice free and open source book available in multiple languages: [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en)
- in case you want to have the repository backed up, or decide to work together with other people, you can easily setup a "remote master" later on, be it on a hosted server or just another of your machines reachable via network

Though it sounds a bit overwhelming, it's not too hard to start with (especially when following up the linked book). I did that a while ago, and am glad about it. For a starter, you can concentrate on a handful of commands (or simply use the GUIs to guide you), such as `git init` (creating a repo), `git add` (adding files to your "staging area" whenever they've been modified), `git commit` (to commit staged changes), `git status` (obviously to check the current status of your working directory), and `git checkout` (to retrieve files from your repository). Then, along the lines of your work, always peek a little deeper in the parameters to those commands, to get more out of it.

[image: gitk] [image: gitcola]
<sup>*gitk* ships with *Git* itself / *gitcola* is available as separate package with most distributions (click images for larger variants)</sup>

*Git* is pretty wide-spread, so in case you need help with it, that should be easy to find. It's also pretty well supported, so you'll find plenty of tools to enhance your setup. Many more arguments I could list up here – but then you wouldn't read my answer as it would get too long :)

Comment: Plus, all technical merits aside, Github is probably the most popular code-sharing site right now.  So if you learn `git`, you can play well with others.